# ionic ios all view blank after keyboard hide

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, keyboard

in ionic login page , every time when i hide keyboard it will cause a full screen blank (element still there can be click and response) , and after editing input all recover normal. (Only iOS,android is fine,other page's input is fine so it should not be the keyboard plugin's problem)

Comment: did you fix this?

Comment: replace <ion-content> with <ion-scroll>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this link help you. But it's temporary.

replace `<ion-content>` with `<ion-scroll>`

`<ion-scroll direction="y" style="right: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;position: absolute;" class="has-header has-subheader">`

[keyboard issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/4849)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: It's actually fix this problem.But seems not the perfect way. Why <ion-content> cause this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this two attributes to ion-content **padding="true"**  **overflow-scroll="false"**

```
<ion-content padding="true" overflow-scroll="false">

</ion-content>
```

It worked for me.